# Change font style for RegEx globally in LaTeX

Tags: regex, latex

Although I know that Latex is a "semantic language", I´m trying to find a solution for the following problem.
In my 60k words document are about 250 strings I can search for via a RegEx, e.g. something like `[A-Z]{2}\d\d[A-Z]{2}` for a string like SE25GH.

Is it possible to define a font style for this RegEx string globally in my document, so that I can change it easily without crawling through my document or typing a defined command like `\makemytextbold{SE25GH}`?

Thanks.